# Looking for an iterative method to fit a beta-exponential distribution to a dataset

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, fitting

I have a messy beta-exponential distribution that has 3 variables that I have to fit to from a dataset with 50 observations.

The problem is that I only know how to use Newton-Raphson for 1 variable.

My question is what optimization method can I use to fit this distribution, in conjunction with the method of maximum likelihood.

If it's possible, please link to a page with a how-to for the optimization method and example code.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for all the help. One of the reasons I was having problems was because deriving the MLE for the beta-exponential distribution was really hard. I thought I could derive it and solve it with matrices but my method was really hard to  implement.

Instead, I used a pre-programmed function in SAS called NLP in order to find my parameters and fit the distribution. This is the code I wrote.

Note1: The data set was in a CSV file.
Note2: The question

Let (,)=∫^(−1)*(1−)^(−1).
A random variable is said to follow a beta-exponential distribution with parameters >0, >0, >0 if it has density
 ()=  (exp((−)/)(1−exp(−/))^(−1))/(,)  >0, 
            0                                                                ≤0.
I had to find parameters alpha, beta, lambda by fitting a given dataset to this distribution.

PROC iml;
use WORK.BETA;
read all into x;
close;

start F_BETTS(param) global(x); /*Calculates MLE*/

```
y= param[1];/* y is lambda*/
a= param[2];/* a is alpha*/
b= param[3];/* b is beta*/
n= nrow(x);
F_BETTS = j(n,1,.);

    do i=1 to n;
    F_BETTS[i]=(exp(-b*x[i]/y)*(1-exp(-x[i]/y))**(a-1))/(y*beta(a,b)); /*Beta-exponential distribution*/
    end;

f = sum(log(F_BETTS));
return(f);
```

finish;

con ={0.01 0.01 0.01,
 . . .};   /*Sets min constraints to barely over 1 and max constraints to infinity*/

Initial={4 2 10}; /* Initial parameter */
opt={1 4}; /* finds maximum with lots of output*/

call nlpnra(rc, xres, "F_BETTS", Initial, opt, con);

run;
quit;

Answer (score 0):

Many packages/libraries offer optimization tools, and some are designed  specifically for maximizing likelihoods (such as computing standard errors of the parameter estimates). You should probably try to take advantage of some of those.

Trying that myself suggests that sometimes the parameters of this distribution may be quite difficult to estimate using the usual optimization tools.

However, there's a neat trick that can sometimes allow you to find the parameter estimates more easily. If you can get ML estimates of parameters for a Beta distribution, you can reduce the original problem to a univariate problem. This is simpler to solve.

Assuming the rate-parameter form of the exponential, my understanding is that the density would be

$f_X(x)=\frac{\lambda \exp(-\lambda x))}{B(\alpha,\beta)}(1-\exp(-\lambda x))^{\alpha-1}(\exp(-\lambda x))^{\beta-1}$

Imagine we knew $\lambda$. Then we could let $Y=1-\exp(-\lambda X)$ so $dy = \lambda \exp(-\lambda x)dx$. Then

$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}(y)^{\alpha-1}(1-y)^{\beta-1},\:0\leq y$,
a beta distribution, which we have assumed we have ML available for.

This allows us to calculate the profile likelihood function $\mathcal{L}(\lambda,(\hat{\alpha},\hat{\beta})(\lambda))$ at each value of $\lambda$, and the value of $\lambda$ at the maximum, $\hat{\lambda}$ (along with the corresponding values for $\hat{\alpha},\hat{\beta}$) will give us the maximizers of the original likelihood.

(Example removed while I investigate a possible problem with it)